# Are Ant path-like structures immutable like properties?

Tags: java, ant

The Ant manual is pretty clear that [properties are immutable](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) (*ie* once a property value is set it cannot be changed by subsequent `<property>` element):

> ### Property
>
> #### Description
>
> Sets a property (by name and value), or set of properties (from file or resource) in the project. Properties are case sensitive.
>
> **Properties are immutable**: whoever sets a property first freezes it for the rest of the build; they are most definitely not variables.

I'm trying to understand whether the same is true [path-like structures](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path) like `<path>`, `<classpath>`, and so on. It's not jumping out at me in the Ant manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike properties, path-like structures are mutable in Ant. Each subsequent update changes the previous version.

### Input `build.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project name="AntPathTest" basedir=".">
    <property name="foo" value="bar"/>
    <property name="foo" value="baz"/>
    <path id="spam">
        <pathelement path="ham"/>
    </path>
    <path id="spam">
        <pathelement path="eggs"/>
    </path>
    <echo message="foo => ${foo}"/>
    <pathconvert property="spam" refid="spam"/>
    <echo message="spam => ${spam}"/>
</project>
```

### Output from `$ ant`

```
Buildfile: /path/to/AntPathTest/build.xml
     [echo] foo => bar
     [echo] spam => /path/to/AntPathTest/eggs
```